# How do I check whether the enclosure failed or the hard drive failed?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, sata, enclosures

I have a spare 500 GB 3.5" internal SATA HDD which I decided to be used as an external HDD. Recently, I bought an 3.5" enclosure ([3.5 inch Cavalry EN-CAXM SuperSpeed USB 3.0 enclosure](http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00YO3R72I)) for this. I am using USB to connect to this to my laptop. For powering, it comes with external power adapter.

The drive shows up in file explorer as a removable disk but upon clicking it, it says:

> "Please insert a disc into removable disk". 
>   In properties, it shows 0 bytes used and 0 bytes free space.

Running `chkdsk` says:

> "Cannot open volume for direct access"

Changing drive letter in disk management did not help. Also, there seems to be no sound of spinning.

**My question is, how do I know what is at fault? The enclosure or the hard disk?** The hard disk was attached to a computer which crashed more than a year ago and had not been used since.

More info: Running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit. Also tried in Vista 32-bit and 7 HP 64-bit.

Comment: Does the HDD work if you connect it by SATA?  I am more inclined to blame the external enclosure then the drive at this point, due to the fact, the enclosure is a generic brand.  **Yes;**  I consider Cavalry to be a generic brand name.

Comment: Multiple [CAXM model numbers](http://www.cavalrystorage.com/caxm.aspx), which one specifically, do you have?

Comment: Sounds like the drive is bad... Have you tried attaching it directly to an embedded SATA port on the mainboard?

Comment: @Ramhound I have included the link in my question. The product package says, EN-CAXM Series. There is no other model number. It is similar to [link]http://www.cavalrystorage.com/caxm.aspx although the looks are different.

Comment: @acejavelin As I have said before, my desktop computer is not working for past one year. It was working than though. I have tried in another laptop but not in any desktop PC. Let me see, if I can check in with some other computer.

Comment: @lorddrake Does it show up in disk management?  Even a USB drive should show up there.  Some times you have to go in there to set it to MBR or GPT, but normally an external HDD should be setup and ready to go as soon as you plug it in.  If it doesn't show up in the disk management, the only other suggestion i would have is take out the HDD and plug it in directly (make sure HDD is fine) and/or talk to Cavalry about possibly getting it swapped out or troubleshooted.

Comment: @lorddrake - There are 5+ models of the EN-CAXM, you have not provided, enough information to identify the one you actually have.

Comment: @dakre18 It shows up in the Disk Management as Disk 1, Removable and No Media.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I the checked the included documentations, the Box, the product itself but there is no other model number. Moreover, the model numbers in the cavalry website vary only by supported capacities. The shopping portal mentions 3TB as the maximum capacity.

Comment: @lorddrake So it shows up, that just means it sees the drive.  What about removing the hard drive from the enclosure, and plugging it directly into the computer to make sure the drive works?  At this point it's either the drive is not working, or the enclosure isn't working.  If it's the enclosure, it's hard to prove hardware issues, but drivers you can reinstall.  So let us know if the hard drive works, and if you know how to uninstall/reinstall the drivers, let us know if that makes a difference (i think it's a hardware issue).

Comment: @lorddrake - Amazon's products descriptions are not always accurate.  They are whatever whom ever added the product wants it to be, which is the reason, they sometimes have formatting problems.

Comment: @dakre18 Yes, as suggested in one of the answers, let me try connecting it without the enclosure. I will get back once I have checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have another spare 3.5" disk, you could try attaching that to your adapter. If it doesn't work, it's probably the adapter.

If you have a spare SATA cable, you could connect the 3.5" disk via SATA, boot Windows, and see if you can access the drive then.  If you can, it's the adapter.

If you have a spare USB memory stick or blank CD, you could put a portable operating system on it (like [pen drive ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)), wire up the SATA power and data cables to the disk you're trying to test (disconnect them from your main disk for now, if you don't have a spare SATA cable), and boot to your bootable medium.  Try to see if you can access the disk from there.

Comment: I do have SATA-SATA and SATA-eSATA cables. My laptop has eSATA port. So, can I connect my drive (without enclosure) to my laptop using SATA-eSATA interface and powering it by connecting it to the power supply of my desktop computer (For testing purpose only). My desktop computer doesn't boot up (seems, there is some issue with the motherboard) but the power supply seems to be working. So, checking it using portable OS is not possible.

Comment: Oh, the computer you're using is a laptop.  In that case, yes, you can probably do that; take a look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/638494/can-i-use-a-second-power-supply-for-hard-drives) and its linked question; it explains separate power supplies for computers.

Comment: I tried connecting the hard drive to my laptop by using SATA-eSATA cable while powering it through my desktop's power supply. It didn't work.

I also tried to use it again in the desktop PC (which wasn't working), it seems that there is no way to check it this way because the display is not receiving any video signals from the CPU. So, I guess, it is better for me to return the enclosure.