# Cannot intitalize Western Digital 320GB SATA WD3200BPVT hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, sata

I bought a Western Digital 320GB SATA WD3200BPVT hard drive, but when I try to initialize it with disk management, i get the error that it cannot initialize it because of an i/o device error. I have tried on all of my computers, but they all say that there was an i/o device error. Is there anyway to fix this, or was this a manufacturing error?

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/1050771/how-do-i-check-whether-the-enclosure-failed-or-the-hard-drive-failed)? You could also try connecting the drive directly or in another computer. Other than that there's isn't nearly enough information in your question for any one to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to hear about your issues with this WD HDD, @05bs001! :( Unfortunately, this is a pretty old WD drive model, so I'd strongly recommend you consider replacing it if you get the I/O error on all your computers. This basically indicates that there could be something physically wrong (hardware corruption) with the HDD. Since you are unable to format it on multiple PCs, you should definitely get this drive replaced by the reseller you bought it from. Make sure you get a replacement that is a newer model and still covered by [our limited warranty](http://support.wdc.com/warranty/policy.asp?wdc_lang=en). Whenever you buy a new hardware, always check its serial number (warranty) to determine if it's genuine or not.

Hope this helps you. Good luck! :)